# RTLinux on Ubuntu 14.10 - AMD x64 machine

Tags: ubuntu-core

Can I install a full PREEMPT kernel on Ubuntu 14.10? I've found a lot of tutorials on the web, but none worked for me, 'cause I think they are out of date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately you can not install rtlinux in new versions of linux, the best linux os for this is redhat 9 if you want i have a virtual image work in virtualbox .

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8y5fr14ju3tnvtz/AAAZ1T8e9m0PKSW_Y9ELSWrKa?dl=0https://www.dropbox.com/sh/8y5fr14ju3tnvtz/AAAZ1T8e9m0PKSW_Y9ELSWrKa?dl=0